# Limit the initial (anchor) values of a recursive query (with statement)

Tags: sqlite, limit, recursive-query, with-statement, subtree

Suppose we perform a recursive query to obtain the children of a certain tree node via an adjacency table of the tree, but it suffices to obtain **only a single sub-tree**.

As an example, let's create the adjacency table of the tree as

```
CREATE TABLE Tree
       (parent INTEGER,
        child  INTEGER);

INSERT INTO Tree
       VALUES -- (parent -> child)
              (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4),
              (2, 5), (2, 11), (3, 9),
              (5, 6), (5, 7),  (5, 8),
              (9, 10), (11, 12);
```

and then make a recursive query to obtain the children of node 2:

```
WITH RECURSIVE children_i (parent, child)
AS (
   -- anchor/initial values
   VALUES (NULL, 2)
   -- SELECT parent, child FROM Tree WHERE parent = 2 LIMIT 1
   UNION ALL
   -- recursion
   SELECT children_i.child, Tree.child FROM Tree, children_i
   WHERE Tree.parent = children_i.child
   )
SELECT * FROM children_i;
```

which will produce

```
|2
2|5
2|11
5|6
5|7
5|8
11|12
```

Now how could we restrict the query above to follow only a *single* sub-tree (say only 2->5->{6, 7, 8} and not 2->11)?
I have tried to add a `LIMIT` to the anchor part of the recursion,

```
WITH RECURSIVE children_i (parent, child)
AS (
   -- anchor/initial values
   SELECT parent, child FROM Tree WHERE parent = 2 LIMIT 1
   UNION ALL
   -- recursion
   SELECT children_i.child, Tree.child FROM Tree, children_i
   WHERE Tree.parent = children_i.child
   )
SELECT * FROM children_i;
```

yet it yields a syntax error, `LIMIT clause should come after UNION ALL not before` (SQLite 3.16.2).

How could one achieve this in SQLite?

Comment: "a _single_ path (say only 2->5->{6, 7, 8}" by that, do you mean that all of 6, 7, 8 should be in the result or just one of them?

Comment: @stickybit: yes, indeed. I expect a result denoting the path 2->5->{6, 7, 8}: A single path from node 2 to the leafs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `LIMIT` but you need to extract it to separate `cte`:

```
WITH anchor AS (
  SELECT parent, child
  FROM tree
  WHERE parent = 2
  -- ORDER BY ...
  LIMIT 1
), children_i(parent,child) AS (
  -- anchor/initial values
  SELECT parent, child
  FROM anchor
  UNION ALL
  -- recursion
  SELECT c1.child, t1.child
  FROM tree t1
  JOIN children_i c1
    ON t1.parent = c1.child
)
SELECT * FROM children_i;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=65f9b59958f8866e9ba7d206f25dbbd6)**

Comment: I like this concise answer +1.
Can we drop `RECURSIVE` from the `with` statement?

Comment: Why `JOIN children_i c1 ON t1.parent = c1.child` instead of `WHERE Tree.parent = children_i.child`?

Comment: @AlQuemist Yes, you can: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f5cac9f90bec0a5af120c11423c14f78

Comment: @AlQuemist `FROM tab1, tab2 WHERE ...` is old style JOIN and should be avoided

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to want is not a path, rather a sub tree with the root node being (only) one of the children of the root of the super tree...

You could limit the child of the root of the super tree by using `NOT EXISTS` and a subquery selecting all children of that root, that are smaller in numerical terms. Like that only that child with the minimum value amongst the children is selected.

```
WITH RECURSIVE children_i
               (parent,
                child)
AS (
-- anchor/initial values
SELECT t1.parent,
       t1.child
       FROM tree t1
       WHERE t1.parent = 2
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM tree t2
                                    WHERE t2.parent = t1.parent
                                          AND t2.child < t1.child)
UNION ALL
-- recursion
SELECT c1.child,
       t1.child
       FROM tree t1
            INNER JOIN children_i c1
                       ON t1.parent = c1.child)
SELECT *
       FROM children_i;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3aa178ae740f5847c16024c6b8a30d31)

Comment: Thanks for the notice; I should correct the wording; I need a single sub-tree (not a path).